# Header div stays at top, vertical scrolling div below with scrollbar only attached body

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Here I'm using bootstrap class for the `sticky top` header.

***header.js***

```
<header className="header sticky-top">HEADER</header>
```

***stylesheet***

```
header {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

This is what I wanted to achive.

```
______________________
|_______header_______|
|                  |*|
|   Container Div  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
----------------------

* = scrollbar
```

This is the example project to work on
[demo code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-demo-forked-vrzm0?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: for that you need to add scroll inside your `container div` and hide body scroll so you can solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the header component into your app like:

```
import Header from "./pages/Header";
```

and actually use it in the JSX:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header></Header>
```

Also to see this in actin the content needs scroll:

[image: Edit React bootstrap demo (forked)]

Comment: Yes that is correct . but I wanted my scrollbar only on body below my header div.

Comment: @Hitheshk then you don't need sticky class https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-demo-forked-swwgl